# Magento2 Database Import Error

Tags: mysql, magento, magento2

I am facing below error when try to import Magento 2 Database to popular hosting company,

`ERROR 1227 (42000) at line 1251: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation`

I read some website/article/blog post and most of place suggested to use `--routines` tag while we do export, so that will remove MySQL Procedure.

Example: `mysqldump --routines`

I stuck since last 3 day and no solution work to import database.

Please help somebody to sort out issue.

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4E5i.jpg)

Comment: It's MySql Procedure issue not MySQL Process. Please correct above in description. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! i have corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same issue and no body can help to you without hosting team. You might have shared hosting and they cant provide supper user privilege, You have to reach to them OR you have to go for own VPS OR Dedicate server.

I personally at that time taken help from Support Team and they imported everything at their end and saved my life :)

Hope it will work fine with you as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Import**

Same Server

```
mysql -u username -p db_name < sql_file.sql
```

Another Server

000.000.0.00 = server ip

```
mysql -u username -p db_name -h 000.000.0.00 < sql_file.sql
```

**Export database**

```
mysqldump -u username -p db_name > sql_file.sql
```